# MassTransit with Azure Service Bus V7: missing property TokenProvider

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I upgraded MassTransit to V7, and it seems there is a breaking change in connecting with Azure Service Bus. Previously, the code for creating an `IBusControl` looked like this:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
  {               
    cfg.Host(this.Host,
      h =>
        {
          h.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(
              "RootManageSharedAccessKey", this.AzureSharedAccessSignatureTokenKey);
        });
...
```

This is not compiling anymore because the property `TokenProvider` is no longer in `IServiceBusHostConfigurator`.

What's the new way of providing the Service Bus access key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure SDK v7 uses `TokenCredential`, which is the new way to specify credentials for all the various v7 SDKs. You can read about it [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet).

So for MassTransit, you'd set `TokenCredential` to any of the supported credential types.

```cs
TokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
```

Answer (score 1):

In V7, the shared access token can be specified in the property `NamedKeyCredential`. So instead of `h.TokenProvider = ...`, we write:

```
h.NamedKeyCredential = new AzureNamedKeyCredential(
    "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
    this.AzureSharedAccessSignatureTokenKey);
```